# SignalR callback after hub actions

Tags: signalr

I am new to SignalR, I apologize if this question is too obvious but I can't find any answer in the documentation.

This is my code.

```
/*1*/   actions.client.doActionA = function (result) {
/*2*/           if(result.Success) 
/*3*/               log(result);
/*4*/           // whatever
/*5*/       };
/*6*/       actions.client.doActionB = function (result) {
/*7*/           if(result.Success) 
/*8*/               log(result);
/*9*/           // whatever
/*10*/       };
/*11*/   
/*12*/       // starts the hub
/*13*/       $.connection.hub.start().done(function () { 
/*14*/          // init UI
/*15*/       });
/*16*/   
/*17*/       // ...after some time...
/*18*/       $.connection.actionsHub.server.doActionA(model);
/*19*/   
/*20*/   my ActionsHub declare the methods
/*21*/   
/*22*/           public void DoActionA (MyModel model)
/*23*/           {
/*24*/               // ... do something
/*25*/               Clients.All.doActionA(result);
/*26*/           }
/*27*/           public void DoActionB (MyModel model)
/*28*/           {
/*29*/               // ... do something
/*30*/               Clients.All.doActionB(result);
/*31*/           }
```

I'd like to be able to execute a function that do something (i.e. *log(result)*), after every command is being executed server side but before the client execution. Is there any option that allows me to do that so that I can avoid to call explicitly the log first for every doActionX?

I'd like the code above to become:

```
   // AFAIK THIS DOESN'T EXIST, IT'S AN EXAMPLE OF WHAT I'M LOOKING FOR!
   actions.client.done(function(data) { log(data);});

   actions.client.doActionA = function (result) {
      // whatever
   };
   actions.client.doActionB = function (result) {
      // whatever
   };

   // starts the hub
   $.connection.hub.start().done(function () { 
      // init UI
   });

   // ...after some time...
   $.connection.actionsHub.server.doActionA(model);
```

Comment: Your code already execute a client function when a method is called from server

Comment: line #3 for example is executed every time it is called from server (#25).

Comment: question edited. I don't want to set that line for every command, I want that log action to be executed automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that functionality on the server via a hub pipeline module.  Sooo here's an article describing it: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-server#hubpipeline.

It happens that the example provided is logging exactly what you're looking for.  If you'd like to see the result of the invocations you can use the OnAfterIncoming override or you can use BuildIncoming.

Here's the base class for a hub pipeline module:
https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core/Hubs/Pipeline/HubPipelineModule.cs and the corresponding docs http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.signalr.hubs.hubpipelinemodule(v=vs.111).aspx

The ability to do this via SignalR on the client is a work in progress:
**JS** - https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/1920
**C#** - https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/1909

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer Taylor - please note the LOG is just an example, I need to do different operations. Are you saying I could invoke that client method from the server?